Error during load model, Skipping variable loading for optimizer 'adam', because it has 90 variables whereas the saved optimizer has 84 variables
I have this error when i try to load my model from exported keras model :
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py:396: UserWarning: Skipping variable loading for optimizer 'adam', because it has 90 variables whereas the saved optimizer has 84 variables. 
  trackable.load_own_variables(weights_store.get(inner_path))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/run.py", line 10, in <module>
    model = load_model('model.keras')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_api.py", line 176, in load_model
    return saving_lib.load_model(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py", line 192, in load_model
    _raise_loading_failure(error_msgs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py", line 273, in _raise_loading_failure
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: A total of 1 objects could not be loaded. Example error message for object <LSTMCell name=lstm_cell, built=True>:

Layer 'lstm_cell' expected 3 variables, but received 0 variables during loading. Expected: ['kernel', 'recurrent_kernel', 'bias']

List of objects that could not be loaded:
[<LSTMCell name=lstm_cell, built=True>]

My code is :
model = keras.models.load_model('model.keras')

My model is a Sequential, i export it with `model.save('model.kearas')
Thanks
I don't know what to try here, I have searched on google.

what version of tensorflow was it made in, and which are you loading to.  The keras 2.0 in the backends doesn't seem to want to play nicely with keras 3.0 in the newer tensorflow when it comes to importing older saved models.

Hi @le_gabi,you are facing an issue when you trying to load saved keras model, the model weight are not matched the expected variable, first you need to check that you are using the same version of tensorflow and Keras use print(tf._version_) to check .You can also try to save and load you model in HDF5 format model.save(‘model.h5) then load it.if you are still facing the issue let me know,Thank you.
